# c# EF Core Migration code First invalid column

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I did several Migrations for my Core-Projekt for SQLite, now i try to switch from SQLite to SQL.

unfortunatly i Get a "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): invalid columnname1 'columnname1'. invalid columnname2 'columnname2'."-Exception with my existing SQL-Statements.

Using something like

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO tablename ('columnname1', 'columnname2 ') VALUES ('columnname1value','columnname2value')");
```

under SQLite it works fine.

I tried to add the "dbo."-Prefix to the Tablename due to different naming convetions between SQL and SQLite. Same Error.

Due to the statements the defined tables in the script were not created in the DB

I tried to seperate the SQL-Statements in a Migration after the table creation. The defined tables are created but Same Error.

making a seed is not an option because in some migrations i use update or delete statements.

What did i wrong with my statement? is it a syntax or a logical problem or did i do it wrong all the time and i was lucky that it works under SQLite.

Thanks for your answers

For All the Other Guys and Ladys with the same Problem. Here my Solution:

**sle1306** got the right Tip. 
Removing the Syntax-Error
I change the quotes to brackets.

To get it work with SQLite And MS SQL:
expand the genertated Code for SQLite on all Tables

```
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false) .Annotation("Autoincrement", true)
```

with/to

```
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false) .Annotation("Autoincrement", true).Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
```

now it works for both of my Databases

Comment: First, remove the quotes for the column names.

Comment: SQL you mean MS SQL? make backup, try to remove all migration, than add new migration and update empty database. also please provide your migration code

Comment: @ sle1306 now i get bad syntax near columnname1 ....

Comment: @itikhomi i give it a Try and reply later

Comment: sle1306 got the right Tip. it was indeed a syntactical problem. But i had to Change the quotes to Brackets instead of removing.
AND to get it work with SQLite and MS SQL i Had to change 
    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Autoincrement", true), in my Code to 
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Autoincrement", true).Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),

Answer (score 0):

For All the Other Guys and Ladys with the same Problem. Here my Solution:

sle1306 got the right Tip. Removing the Syntax-Error I change the quotes to brackets.

To get it work with SQLite And MS SQL: expand the genertated Code for SQLite on all Tables

```
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false) .Annotation("Autoincrement", true)
```

with/to

```
Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false) .Annotation("Autoincrement", true).Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
```

now it works for both of my Databases